# i want to datafram from the list which has dict inside

Tags: python

```
[{'id': 523535,
  'type': 'array',
  'name': 'Index',
  'value': '- rea - das - faA -\n'},
 {'id': 425322,
  'type': 'array',
  'name': 'status',
  'value': '321 - 323 -  - B332\n'},
 {'id': 425322, 'type': 'array', 'name': 'Index', 'value': 'I'},
 {'id': 527942, 'type': 'array', 'name': 'status', 'value': 'BF'}]
```

I want to data-frame which only name and value.

where column names are Freigabestatus and Index,
and their values are BF and I
as you can see below.

```
 _____________________
|Freigabestatus |Index|
_______________________
| BF            |I    |
_______________________
```

Comment: @NewbieAF yes! The below example is also given where the column name should be  Freigabestatus and Index. where values of column both column should be BF and I respectively.

Comment: But in your example, the column names aren't names and values. They are specific names and the values are specific values. You see why it's confusing?

Comment: @NewbieAF Yes, you are correct. I need a data-frame showing the below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
lst = [{'id': 1050881,
  'type': 'array',
  'name': 'Index',
  'value': '- AF - H04 - SCA -\n'},
 {'id': 1050882,
  'type': 'array',
  'name': 'Freigabestatus',
  'value': 'U1 - 000 - I - BF\n'},
 {'id': 1050909, 'type': 'array', 'name': 'Index', 'value': 'I'},
 {'id': 1050949, 'type': 'array', 'name': 'Freigabestatus', 'value': 'BF'}]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Freigabestatus': [d['value'] for d in lst if d['name'] =='Freigabestatus']})
df['Index'] = [d['value'] for d in lst if d['name'] == 'Index']
df
```

Comment: thank you so much:) I got two rows  ```Freigabestatus Index
0 U1 - 000 - I - BF\n - AF - H04 - SCA -\n
1 BF I```

Comment: need only one row of BF and I

Comment: Then there was no need for all this. Just have a look into [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and see the examples there.